# Zabbix: What is the difference between `HostMetadata` and `HostMetadataItem`?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

Question = headline ;-)

Official docs [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agentd). I've read [this example](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/discovery/auto_registration) too, but still don't have a clue.

Additional question: How can I specify multiple meta items? E.g. env=staging,server=db.

*I would like to chose a template automatically after a client auto registers.*

An additional example showing the differences would be awesome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*HostMetadataItem* is an item key that will be evaluated and the result sent as *HostMetadata*, for example, *system.uname*

*HostMetadata* is just user defined string. Write there, what do you need. Example of Zabbix agent HostMetadataItem setting:

```
HostMetadata=:osname=Linux:env=staging:color=blue:docker=yes:app=apache:
```

Example Zabbix autoregistration with condition&operation for HostMetadataItem example above:

- Condition: Host metadata like *:osname=Linux:*; Operation: Link to templates: Template OS Linux
- Condition: Host metadata like *:docker=yes:*; Operation: Link to templates: Template App Docker
- Condition: Host metadata like *:app=apache:*; Operation: Link to templates: Template App Apache
- Condition: Host metadata like *:env=staging:*; Operation: Add to host groups: Staging servers
- Condition: Host metadata like *:color=blue:*; Operation: Add to host groups: Blue servers
- ...

If your autoregistration rules are complete, then you can delete your hosts from the Zabbix UI anytime. They will be autoregistered back in a few minutes with the right templates/group.

Comment: This should be part of the docs.

Comment: To clarify, HostMetadataItem is an item key that will be evaluated and the result sent as metadata - calling it a "command" might be confusing.

Comment: @Richlv You are right. My answer has been updated. Thank you.